# Customize React Native DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm using the [React Native DateTimePicker](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker) and I'd like to open the picker by using a separate button. I'm fairly new to React Native so I'm not entirely sure this is possible.

The top is what I'd like to use to trigger opening the picker, the bottom is the default button from the package.
[image: DateTimePicker and custom button]

I understand I can customize the styling but that it'd only work on IOS, so I'm wondering if this is possible or I need to search for a different Date Picker package. Thank you for any help.